# Prepositions for places "at", "in" or "on"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am concerned about what preposition I should use in this sentence.

> We met at an event.
>   or
>   We met on an event.

Basically, when I have to use prepositions for places I get really confused between "on" and "at". Sometimes I even wonder if it should be "in". So can you please teach me how and when to use these 3 prepositions for places?

Comment: In general: at a place and on a date. I met her on Tuesday at the station. But: I met her on Tuesday on the roof or  on the beach. ON is for places you stand on. I met her on the dance floor. BUT: I met her at the dance. You have to start and feel the difference. It takes times, give yourself a break. :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely "at an event" but "on holiday" or "on a training course". That would be consistent with going **to** an  event but going on holiday or a course.

Comment: Yes, to meet someone on holiday, on a training course. In addition to: on the roof or on the beach, for example.